# Opacity in bottom of the text while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put Opacity on the bottom of this text and it should stay so while scrolling, but when I scroll at the end it should be seen.
How can I do this ?

Here is my code:

```
//html

large text goes here



//css

     #wrapper {
            height: 600px;
            width: 700px;
            overflow: auto;
            position: absolute;
            left: 25%;
              }
```

Comment: Last time checked `large text goes here` was invalid HTML. Provide all the code

Comment: provide fiddle to understand..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bulina/rVG5C/

Comment: @laaposto http://jsfiddle.net/bulina/rVG5C/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the `#wrapper` CSS:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left 20%,left bottom,from(black),to(rgba(0,0,0,0)))
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/M6VeG/)

Comment: Nice solution but it only works in webkit enabled browsers :(

Answer (score 1):

For a cross-browser ([Internet Explorer greater or equal than 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient)) solution you can do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  content here
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g192m935/)

Comment: @Bulina are you using IE 10/11? You can change the height variable in overlay to make it "thicker".

Comment: @Bulina You can make a [fallback for those browsers](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) with a gradient background-image.